# How To place Both Logo and text in the Same Line?

Tags: html, css

what is the HTML with CSS Code to align have logo and text  in the same line...that it must look as shown in the below pattern..

```
    HTML:

     <div class="top_left">
     <div class="header"> 
     <img src="https://b.fastcompany.net/multisite_files/fastcompany/imagecache/inline-small/inline/2015/09/3050613-inline-i-2-googles-new-logo-copy.png" alt="logo"/>             <br/>
     </div>
     <h2 id="site-title"><a>GOOGLE</a>
     <div id="site-description">SEARCH ENGINE </div>
     </h2>
     </div>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so that we can help you out. We cannot assume and write code for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following html/css combo:

```css
/* CSS */

.container-div {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 250px;
   height: 150px;
}

.img-div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-div img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.img-placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.5%;
  left: 15%;
}

.text-div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="container-div">

  <div class="img-div">
    <img />
    <p class="img-placeholder">
      Image Goes Here
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="text-div">
  
    <h2>
      Texty-text
    </h2>
    
    <p>
      Sub-texty-text
    </p>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<p><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/27/21/03/lone-tree-1934897_960_720.jpg" alt="imag" style="height: 50px;width: 50px;"><span>kiran</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

hello try to make a container for the logo and the text and a few div with a float that would do the job if i am right
like this

```html
<div class="name of class you made" //give jut a with>
  <div class="logo" //put float in this with a with>logo</div><div class="tekst" //put float in this with a with>tekst</div>
</div>
```

i am not sure but this would help

Answer (score 0):

You can either use (on the h4 elements, as they are block by default)

`display: inline-block;`

Or you can float the elements to the left/rght

`float: left;`

Just don't forget to clear the floats after

`clear: left;`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<div class="container">
     <div id="logo">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
     </div>
    <div id="text">
        <h2>Hello</h2>
        <h3>World</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container > div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

#logo, #text {
    float: left;
}
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjpn66nb/)